# 10 day grace period on my 180 day server 2012 evaluation?

Tags: windows-server-2012, licensing

I just installed an eval copy of windows server 2012 (datacenter) core.

It says its a 180 evaluation, but checking the licensing info I see this:

[image]

Is this different for core installs than GUI because I have used the same iso to do full GUI installs and it always gives me 180 days.

I should also add when downloading the trail I was not provided a license key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never activated it online...you have to do that to allow for the full 180 days.

> For all editions, you have 10 days to complete online activation, at
>   which point the evaluation period begins and runs for 180 days.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574204.aspx

Comment: c:\Windows\System32>cscript.exe slmgr.vbs -ato

Comment: yep...same as the GUI.  There ya go.

Comment: Felt silly after asking this because I just remembered having to do it for my previous full GUI installs. I guess because this was a core install I never saw the watermark and totally forgot about it.